# Getting "value without a container" error

Tags: raku

Got this:

```
for $config.IO.slurp.lines <-> $l {
  $l .= trim;
  ...
}
```

Get this:

```
t/01-basic.rakutest ..3/5
Parameter '$l' expects a writable container (variable) as an argument,
but got '# karabiner config file' (Str) as a value without a container.
  in sub generate_file at...
```

I've read the docs on containers but it didn't shed any light on what I can do in this situation aside from maybe assigning `$l` to a scalar variable, which seems hacky. Is there a way I can containerize `$l`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue is really that `.lines` does not produce containers.  So with `<->`, you would bind to the value, rather than a container.  There are several ways to solve this, by containerizing as you suggested:

```
for $config.IO.slurp.lines -> $l is copy {
    $l .= trim;
    ...
}
```

But that only makes sense if you want to do more changes to `$l`.  If this is really just about trimming the line that you receive, you could do this on the fly:

```
for $config.IO.slurp.lines>>.trim -> $l {
    ...
}
```

Or, if you need to do more pre-processing `$l`, use a `.map`:

```
for $config.IO.slurp.lines.map({
    .trim.subst("foo","bar",:g)
}) -> $l {
    ...
}
```

Comment: For those like me who don't know, the `>>` is hyper operator: https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#Hyper_operators

Answer (score 0):

Maybe below is what you want? Generally, you read a file via `slurp` you can comfortably handle its size, or you read a file via `lines` if you want input taken in lazily, one-line-at-a-time:

```
my $config = 'alphabet_one_letter_per_line.txt';

my $txt1 = $config.IO.slurp; 
$txt1.elems.say; #1
$txt1.print; #returns alphabet same as input

my $txt2 = $config.IO.lines;
$txt2.elems.say; #26
$txt2.join("\n").put; #returns alphabet same as input
```

Above, you get only `1` element when `slurp`ing, but `26` elements when reading `lines`. As you can see from the above code, there's no need to *"...(assign) `$l` to a scalar variable..."* because there's no need to create (temporary variable) `$l`.

You can store text in `@txt` arrays, and get the same number of elements as above. And you can just call routines on your stored text, as you have been doing (example below continues `$txt2` example above):

```
$txt2.=map(*.uc);
say $txt2;
```

Sample Output:

```
(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
```

*[Note, this question seems to have triggered questions on the use of `$txt2.=map(*.uc);` versus `$txt2.=uc;`. My rule-of-thumb is simple: if the data structure I'm working on has more than one element, I `map` using `*` 'whatever-star' to address the routine call to each element].*

https://docs.raku.org/

Comment: Why the `.map` in `$txt2 .= map(*.uc)` ??   Why not `$txt2 .= uc` ?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen because it works? And because--if I consistently `map` into elements of a $-sigiled scalar (or even an @-sigiled array)--I usually get the output I desire (without relying on any inherent Raku DWIMmy-ness... ).